# On sections of the tangent bundle of a Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Being more familiar with linear operators than with geometry, I like to see $G_K(r,n)$, the Grassmannian of all $r$ dimensional subspaces in $K^{r+n}$ ($K=\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$), as the set of all rank $k$ projections (self-adjoint idempotents) in $M_n(K)$. And I am also interested in the infinite-dimensional Grassmannians sitting in $B(H)$, the algebra of bounded linear operators on a separable infinite-dimensional $K$ Hilbert space. In the latter, the projections split into connected components according to their rank and their nullity. These are smooth manifolds, but modelled on an infinite-dimensional (for $r\neq 0$ and $n\neq 0$) Banach space. They are the infinite-dimensional analogues of the above. I cheated with the usual notations to include the latter: for instance, $G_\mathbb{C}(3,\infty)$ corresponds to the rank $3$ projections in $B(H)$.

Thinking about some linear questions, I ended up being interested in the following: does there exist a nowhere vanishing section of the tangent bundle of $G_K(r,n)$? The two cases I am really comfortable with are $G_\mathbb{R}(1,1)$ (yes, that's $S^1$ and the tangent bundle is trivial), and $G_\mathbb{C}(1,1)$ (no, by the hairy ball theorem since it is $S^2$).

I vaguely know that under some conditions, the tangent bundle of a manifold admits a nowhere vanishing section if and only if its Euler class (or should  say number?) is zero. And that under some conditions, this coincides with the Euler characteristic of the manifold.

**Questions:**

> 1 - What is a precise statement and set of conditions for the latter, hopefully applying to the (possibly infinite-dimensional) Grassmannians?
>
> 2 - If it applies, what are the relevant Euler invariants (characteristic/class/number) for $G_K(r,n)$? After a lot of googling, I think I found $\binom{r+n}{r}$ in the complex case (without being sure because I am having a hard time understanding the geometric language). Is this true? What does the number mean exactly? What about the real case? What about the infinite-dimensional case?
>
> 3 - Ultimately, I am mostly interested in knowing when I can say that any section of the tangent bundle of $G_K(r,n)$ must vanish, and how to justify it properly. Could you clarify this for me?
>
> 4 - I think it is about time for me to understand these things. Do you know a friendly reference for someone who has a lot of difficulty with geometry?

Thank you.

**Edit:** forget the infinite-dimensional analogue. In $B(H)$, the unitary group is much less twisted than in $M_n$. A famous theorem of Kuiper shows that it is contractible. If I am not mistaken, this entails that the Grassmannians of $B(H)$ have a trivial tangent bundle.

Comment: Is that a "protesting" nickname? =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 and 2) The precise statement is usually given in the Poincare-Hopf index theorem. The computation of the Euler characteristic involves the binomial coefficients, yes.  And I think you have the answer in the complex case correct.  Sometimes in the Poincare-Hopf index theorem they fail to mention that if the euler characteristic is zero (on a connected manifold), you can find a vector field with no zeros.  But the proof in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic classes* book shows you how to do it.

3) I put the computation of the Euler characteristic of the Grassmann manifolds in the Wikipedia page (look at the Schubert cell section) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian

4) This work is not algebraic geometry. It is differential topology. It's written up well in Guillemin and Pollack. Also in Bredon's Algebraic Topology text

Comment: Thank you very much. Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) the correct statement? It does not even state the other direction: that if there is a nowhere vanishing section, the Euler characteristic is $0$. Is it implicit in that the sum on the left is zero if void? Also, are there any known generalizations in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: Yes, sums over an empty set are conventionally taken to be zero.  What infinite-dimensional case are you referring to, could you be precise?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since the complex Grassmannians are orientable, and the real ones are orientable iff $n$ is even, Poincare-Hopf answers my question in the finite-dimensional case, except for the real case in odd dimension. That's great, thanks again.

Comment: I'm confused why you make the distinction orientable/non-orientable.  If the Euler characteristic is zero, the manifold has an everywhere non-zero vector field, even if the manifold is non-orientable.